# Display Null as 0 in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]Trying to display `NULL` as `zero` in my report.

- `ISNULL(course, ' ')`  - this works and displays null cells as blanks
- `ISNULL(count(course), '')`  - this does not work

I tried `ISNothing` using SQL Server 12 to display the count as zero, it did not.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Please include the entire query.

Comment: To improve the quality of your Question, please show us the entire query that you are using and prefereably the structure of your tables along with some sample data.  Also, please show us the desired output based on your sample data.

Comment: If you're not getting any results for count(column), it's likely because your query looks something like the following: `SELECT COUNT(column) FROM mytable WHERE somecolumn = somecondition GROUP BY somecolumn;` and there are no records where somecolumn = somecondition. In this case, your count _is_ 0 but you won't get a result set at all (this is to do with the way WHERE and GROUP BY work with COUNT). One solution is putting your entire query inside an isnull statement. e.g. `SELECT ISNULL((SELECT COUNT(column) FROM myTable...), 0)`

Comment: @CognosBee what does the 'select count(course) from yourtable' return? 0 or null?

Comment: Please *[edit]* your question to show us your code. Code in comments is unreadable. Code in your question can be put in a code block (the `{}` button) and then it maintains its structure and turns on syntax highlighting too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code was...

```
SELECT college,
       department,
       COUNT( department ),
       MONTH( [date] ),
       CASE
           WHEN DATEPART( MONTH, [date] ) = 1 THEN
               ISNULL( COUNT( department ),
                       ' ' )
           END AS 'January',
       CASE
           WHEN DATEPART( MONTH, [date] ) = 2 THEN
               ISNULL( COUNT( department ),
                       ' ' )
           END AS 'February'
FROM rpt_school
GROUP BY college,
         department,
         MONTH( [date] );
```

If your intent is to get a list of colleges, departments within each college, the number of records for each department within each college, and the number of records for `January` or `February` for each department within each college, then I suggest the following...

```
SELECT college,
       department,
       COUNT( department ) AS departmentCount,
       COUNT( CASE
                  WHEN DATEPART( MONTH, [date] ) = 1 THEN
                      1
              END
            ) AS 'January',
       COUNT( CASE
                  WHEN DATEPART( MONTH, [date] ) = 2 THEN
                      1
              END
            ) AS 'February'
FROM rpt_school
GROUP BY college,
         department;
```

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

*Appendix*

To get a list of `college`s, `department`s within each `college`, and counts of `date`s associated with each department within each college by `month`, please try the following...

```
SELECT collegeDepartments.college AS college,
       collegeDepartments.department AS department,
       COUNT( CASE
                  WHEN monthNumber = 1 THEN
                      COALESCE( countOfMonthNumber, 0 )
                  ELSE
                      0
              END
            ) AS 'January',
       COUNT( CASE
                  WHEN monthNumber = 2 THEN
                      COALESCE( countOfMonthNumber, 0 )
                  ELSE
                      0
              END
            ) AS 'February',
       COUNT( CASE
                  WHEN monthNumber = 3 THEN
                      COALESCE( countOfMonthNumber, 0 )
                  ELSE
                      0
              END
            ) AS 'March',
       COUNT( CASE
                  WHEN monthNumber = 4 THEN
                      COALESCE( countOfMonthNumber, 0 )
                  ELSE
                      0
              END
            ) AS 'April',
       COUNT( CASE
                  WHEN monthNumber = 5 THEN
                      COALESCE( countOfMonthNumber, 0 )
                  ELSE
                      0
              END
            ) AS 'May',
       COUNT( CASE
                  WHEN monthNumber = 6 THEN
                      COALESCE( countOfMonthNumber, 0 )
                  ELSE
                      0
              END
            ) AS 'June',
       COUNT( CASE
                  WHEN monthNumber = 7 THEN
                      COALESCE( countOfMonthNumber, 0 )
                  ELSE
                      0
              END
            ) AS 'July',
       COUNT( CASE
                  WHEN monthNumber = 8 THEN
                      COALESCE( countOfMonthNumber, 0 )
                  ELSE
                      0
              END
            ) AS 'August',
       COUNT( CASE
                  WHEN monthNumber = 9 THEN
                      COALESCE( countOfMonthNumber, 0 )
                  ELSE
                      0
              END
            ) AS 'September',
       COUNT( CASE
                  WHEN monthNumber = 10 THEN
                      COALESCE( countOfMonthNumber, 0 )
                  ELSE
                      0
              END
            ) AS 'October',
       COUNT( CASE
                  WHEN monthNumber = 11 THEN
                      COALESCE( countOfMonthNumber, 0 )
                  ELSE
                      0
              END
            ) AS 'November',
       COUNT( CASE
                  WHEN monthNumber = 12 THEN
                      COALESCE( countOfMonthNumber, 0 )
                  ELSE
                      0
              END
            ) AS 'December'
FROM ( SELECT college AS college,
              department AS department,
              monthNumber AS monthNumber
       FROM ( SELECT college AS college,
              department AS department
              FROM rpt_school
              GROUP BY college,
                       department
            ) AS collegeDepartments,
            ( SELECT 1 AS monthNumber
              UNION SELECT 2
              UNION SELECT 3
              UNION SELECT 4
              UNION SELECT 5
              UNION SELECT 6
              UNION SELECT 7
              UNION SELECT 8
              UNION SELECT 9
              UNION SELECT 10
              UNION SELECT 11
              UNION SELECT 12
            ) AS monthNumbers
     ) AS collegeDepartmentsMonthNumbers
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT college AS college,
                   department AS department,
                   DATEPART( MONTH, rpt_school.[date] ) AS monthNumber,
                   COUNT( * ) AS countOfMonthNumber
            FROM rpt_school
            GROUP BY college,
                     department,
                     monthNumber
          ) AS countOfMonthPartFinder ON collegeDepartmentsMonthNumbers.college = countOfMonthPartFinder.college
                                AND collegeDepartmentsMonthNumbers.department = countOfMonthPartFinder.department
                                AND collegeDepartmentsMonthNumbers.monthNumber = countOfMonthPartFinder.monthNumber
ORDER BY college,
         department,
         collegeDepartmentsMonthNumbers.monthNumber;
```

This statement starts with the following subquery...

```
SELECT college AS college,
       department AS department
FROM rpt_school
GROUP BY college,
         department
```

This subquery compiles a list of unique combinations of `college` and `department` from `rpt_school`.  Performing this grouping now rather than later eliminates alot of joining and should make the overall statement more efficient.

A `CROSS JOIN` is then performed on the results of this subquery and those of the following subquery...

```
SELECT 1 AS monthNumber
UNION SELECT 2
UNION SELECT 3
UNION SELECT 4
UNION SELECT 5
UNION SELECT 6
UNION SELECT 7
UNION SELECT 8
UNION SELECT 9
UNION SELECT 10
UNION SELECT 11
UNION SELECT 12
```

This subquery creates a list of each month number.  The `CROSS JOIN` performed has the effect of appending a list of each month number to each unique combination of `college` and `department`.  The fields of this `CROSS JOIN`ed dataset are then returned to the main statement by selecting the each field fo the dataset, as per the following...

```
SELECT college AS college,
       department AS department,
       monthNumber AS monthNumber
FROM ( SELECT college AS college,
              department AS department
       FROM rpt_school
       GROUP BY college,
                department
     ) AS collegeDepartments,
     ( SELECT 1 AS monthNumber
       UNION SELECT 2
       UNION SELECT 3
       UNION SELECT 4
       UNION SELECT 5
       UNION SELECT 6
       UNION SELECT 7
       UNION SELECT 8
       UNION SELECT 9
       UNION SELECT 10
       UNION SELECT 11
       UNION SELECT 12
     ) AS monthNumbers
```

Please note that the syntax for a `CROSS JOIN` between two tables is `tblTable1, tblTable2`.

The `CROSS JOIN`ed dataset is then `LEFT JOIN`ed to a subquery that finds the count of `dates` belonging to a particular `month` for each `department` within each `college`, as per the following...

```
JOIN ( SELECT college AS college,
              department AS department,
              DATEPART( MONTH, rpt_school.[date] ) AS monthNumber,
              COUNT( * ) AS countOfMonthNumber
       FROM rpt_school
       GROUP BY college,
                department,
                monthNumber
     ) AS countOfMonthPartFinder ON collegeDepartmentsMonthNumbers.college = countOfMonthPartFinder.college
                                AND collegeDepartmentsMonthNumbers.department = countOfMonthPartFinder.department
                                AND collegeDepartmentsMonthNumbers.monthNumber = countOfMonthPartFinder.monthNumber
```

The `college` and `department` from our now finally joined dataset  is then selected and a series of `CASE` statements that will return the count of the current month's records or a zero as appropriate.

Comment: Is `hb.ate` a field or should that be `hb.date`?

Comment: Answer updated.  Is this closer to what you are wanting to achieve?

Comment: Yes, I can do the same for whole year.  Cheers.

Comment: I don't know what version of sql server but you may be able to replace the case statement with IIF.

Comment: `sam yi`, Nice job spotting the error.  Thank you for the edit.

Comment: How can I combine the three rows in one? college, department, January, February, March Art-------Music-------1 -------0------- 0 Art-------Music-------0 -------2------- 0 Art-------Music-------0 -------0------- 3 Using this code: toonice has provided?

Comment: Please explain the extra columns.  Are you asking for a list of colleges, the count of dates associated with each college by month, and the count of dates for each department within each college, or something else?

Comment: I added a capture.

Comment: Thanks toonice, you saved me a big time.

Comment: Please be advised that I spotted a minor flaw in my code.  The corrected version has been posted.

Answer (score 0):

can do this also:

```
select case when course  is null then '0' else course end
```

It accept even text.

Comment: Because if it just change null value to 0 you got an error with convertion failed ..... data type to int. i'm just thinking if your course field is varchar datatype

Comment: Yes, the data type is varchar

Comment: then you can use '0' with single quote to avoid error.

Comment: It did not like "Is Null'... goes red.

Comment: you can use also like this to avoid spaces. "select case when course  is null or len(replace(course,' ',''))<1 then '' else course end"

Comment: it can be also like this.. "select case when course  is null or len(replace(course,' ',''))<1 then 'zero' else course end"

Answer (score 0):

In sample data we have two null values and its count is shown AS 2

```
    Declare @Course TABLE (Course VARCHAR(50))
    Insert INTO @Course
    SELECT 'ABC'    Union all
    SELECT NUll  Union all
    SELECT 'ABC'     Union all
    SELECT NUll  Union all
    SELECT 'dfg'    
SELECT Course,COUNT(ISNULL( NULLIF(Course, NULL) ,'0'))AS CourseCount
FROM @Course
Group by Course
```

OutPut

```
Rno |Course |CourseCount
------------------------
1   |NULL   |2
2   |ABC    |2
3   |dfg    |1
```

Comment: I think I have a new problem.

Comment: I have one row for each month which causes the report runs very long.  For example

Comment: How can I combine the three rows in one?

college, department, January, February, March 
Art-------Music-------1 -------0------- 0 
Art-------Music-------0 -------2------- 0       
Art-------Music-------0 -------0------- 3

Using this code: toonice has provided?